# Follow https link from outlook message body with Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a task to follow first of two links which is contained in Outlook body and avoid second link. 
Body example:

True link: http://metallica.com/

Link to avoid: https://black-star.ru/

[image]

I can only handle the message but then i don't know what to do.

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you could use [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#contains) to check whether the message has the link string. It will return true if the string is found.

```
contains(outputs('Compose'),'string')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank's! It's useful option but my problem is that the message will contain two links, and first one i gonna follow and avoid second one.  So I need to take first link from messages body and follow it.  Correct link is always first one.